# curving text using button jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, curve

i would like to know how i can make more designs using http://circletype.labwire.ca/#fitText  i was succesful on making one but that is about it it only makes a circle i cant make more designs something is wrong with my code can someone please help? also how can i make wedge text and "wiggle" text one last thing i would also like to know how to make spiral text if some one knows any of these it would be a great help

```js
$("#fs").change(function() {
    //alert($(this).val());
    $('.changeMe').css("font-family", $(this).val());

});

$("#size").change(function() {
    $('.changeMe').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});







  $("#demo1").click(function(){
   $('.changeMe').circleType("fitText:true",     $(this).attr('radius: 180'));
  });


/**
 * Arctext.js
 * A jQuery plugin for curved text
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Copyright 2011, Pedro Botelho / Codrops
 * Free to use under the MIT license.
 *
 * Date: Mon Jan 23 2012
 */

(function( $, undefined ) {
 
 /*! 
 * FitText.js 1.0
 *
 * Copyright 2011, Dave Rupert http://daverupert.com
 * Released under the WTFPL license 
 * http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/
 *
 * Date: Thu May 05 14:23:00 2011 -0600
 */
 $.fn.fitText = function( kompressor, options ) {

     var settings = {
   'minFontSize' : Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
   'maxFontSize' : Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
  };

  return this.each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);              // store the object
   var compressor = kompressor || 1; // set the compressor
 
   if ( options ) { 
     $.extend( settings, options );
   }
 
   // Resizer() resizes items based on the object width divided by the compressor * 10
   var resizer = function () {
    $this.css('font-size', Math.max(Math.min($this.width() / (compressor*10), parseFloat(settings.maxFontSize)), parseFloat(settings.minFontSize)));
   };

   // Call once to set.
   resizer();

   // Call on resize. Opera debounces their resize by default. 
   $(window).resize(resizer);
  });

 };

 /*
  * Lettering plugin
  *
  * changed injector function:
  *   add &nbsp; for empty chars.
  */
 function injector(t, splitter, klass, after) {
  var a = t.text().split(splitter), inject = '', emptyclass;
  if (a.length) {
   $(a).each(function(i, item) {
    emptyclass = '';
    if(item === ' ') {
     emptyclass = ' empty';
     item='&nbsp;';
    } 
    inject += '<span class="'+klass+(i+1)+emptyclass+'">'+item+'</span>'+after;
   }); 
   t.empty().append(inject);
  }
 }
 
 var methods    = {
  init : function() {

   return this.each(function() {
    injector($(this), '', 'char', '');
   });

  },

  words : function() {

   return this.each(function() {
    injector($(this), ' ', 'word', ' ');
   });

  },
  
  lines : function() {

   return this.each(function() {
    var r = "eefec303079ad17405c889e092e105b0";
    // Because it's hard to split a <br/> tag consistently across browsers,
    // (*ahem* IE *ahem*), we replaces all <br/> instances with an md5 hash 
    // (of the word "split").  If you're trying to use this plugin on that 
    // md5 hash string, it will fail because you're being ridiculous.
    injector($(this).children("br").replaceWith(r).end(), r, 'line', '');
   });

  }
 };

 $.fn.lettering    = function( method ) {
  // Method calling logic
  if ( method && methods[method] ) {
   return methods[ method ].apply( this, [].slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
  } else if ( method === 'letters' || ! method ) {
   return methods.init.apply( this, [].slice.call( arguments, 0 ) ); // always pass an array
  }
  $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.lettering' );
  return this;
 };
 
 /*
  * Arctext object.
  */
 $.Arctext     = function( options, element ) {
 
  this.$el = $( element );
  this._init( options );
  
 };
 
 $.Arctext.defaults   = {
  radius : 0,  // the minimum value allowed is half of the word length. if set to -1, the word will be straight.
  dir  : 1, // 1: curve is down, -1: curve is up.
  rotate : true, // if true each letter will be rotated.
  fitText : false // if you wanna try out the fitText plugin (http://fittextjs.com/) set this to true. Don't forget the wrapper should be fluid.
    };
 
 $.Arctext.prototype  = {
  _init     : function( options ) {
   
   this.options   = $.extend( true, {}, $.Arctext.defaults, options );
   
   // apply the lettering plugin.
   this._applyLettering();
   
   this.$el.data( 'arctext', true );
   
   // calculate values
   this._calc();
   
   // apply transformation.
   this._rotateWord();
   
   // load the events
   this._loadEvents();
   
  },
  _applyLettering  : function() {
  
   this.$el.lettering();
   
   if( this.options.fitText )
    this.$el.fitText();
   
   this.$letters = this.$el.find('span').css('display', 'inline-block');
  
  },
  _calc    : function() {
   
   if( this.options.radius === -1 )
    return false;
   
   // calculate word / arc sizes & distances.
   this._calcBase();
   
   // get final values for each letter.
   this._calcLetters();
  
  },
  _calcBase   : function() {
   
   // total word width (sum of letters widths)
   this.dtWord  = 0;
   
   var _self   = this;
   
   this.$letters.each( function(i) {
        
    var $letter   = $(this),
     letterWidth  = $letter.outerWidth( true );
    
    _self.dtWord += letterWidth;
    
    // save the center point of each letter:
    $letter.data( 'center', _self.dtWord - letterWidth / 2 );
    
   });
   
   // the middle point of the word.
   var centerWord = this.dtWord / 2;
   
   // check radius : the minimum value allowed is half of the word length.
   if( this.options.radius < centerWord )
    this.options.radius = centerWord;
   
   // total arc segment length, where the letters will be placed.
   this.dtArcBase = this.dtWord;
   
   // calculate the arc (length) that goes from the beginning of the first letter (x=0) to the end of the last letter (x=this.dtWord).
   // first lets calculate the angle for the triangle with base = this.dtArcBase and the other two sides = radius.
   var angle  = 2 * Math.asin( this.dtArcBase / ( 2 * this.options.radius ) );
   
   // given the formula: L(ength) = R(adius) x A(ngle), we calculate our arc length.
   this.dtArc  = this.options.radius * angle;
   
  },
  _calcLetters  : function() {
   
   var _self   = this,
    iteratorX  = 0;
    
   this.$letters.each( function(i) {
     
    var $letter   = $(this),
     // calculate each letter's semi arc given the percentage of each letter on the original word.
     dtArcLetter  = ( $letter.outerWidth( true ) / _self.dtWord ) * _self.dtArc,
     // angle for the dtArcLetter given our radius.
     beta   = dtArcLetter / _self.options.radius,
     // distance from the middle point of the semi arc's chord to the center of the circle.
     // this is going to be the place where the letter will be positioned.
     h    = _self.options.radius * ( Math.cos( beta / 2 ) ),
     // angle formed by the x-axis and the left most point of the chord.
     alpha   = Math.acos( ( _self.dtWord / 2 - iteratorX ) / _self.options.radius ),
     // angle formed by the x-axis and the right most point of the chord.
     theta    = alpha + beta / 2,
     // distances of the sides of the triangle formed by h and the orthogonal to the x-axis.
     x    = Math.cos( theta ) * h,
     y    = Math.sin( theta ) * h,
     // the value for the coordinate x of the middle point of the chord.
     xpos   = iteratorX + Math.abs( _self.dtWord / 2 - x - iteratorX ),
     // finally, calculate how much to translate each letter, given its center point.
     // also calculate the angle to rotate the letter accordingly.
     xval = 0| xpos - $letter.data( 'center' ),
     yval = 0| _self.options.radius - y,
     angle  = ( _self.options.rotate ) ? 0| -Math.asin( x / _self.options.radius ) * ( 180 / Math.PI ) : 0;
    
    // the iteratorX will be positioned on the second point of each semi arc
    iteratorX = 2 * xpos - iteratorX;
    
    // save these values
    $letter.data({
     x : xval,
     y : ( _self.options.dir === 1 ) ? yval : -yval,
     a : ( _self.options.dir === 1 ) ? angle : -angle
    });
     
   });
  
  },
  _rotateWord   : function( animation ) {
   
   if( !this.$el.data('arctext') ) return false;
   
   var _self = this;
   
   this.$letters.each( function(i) {
    
    var $letter   = $(this),
     transformation = ( _self.options.radius === -1 ) ? 'none' : 'translateX(' + $letter.data('x') + 'px) translateY(' + $letter.data('y') + 'px) rotate(' + $letter.data('a') + 'deg)',
     transition  = ( animation ) ? 'all ' + ( animation.speed || 0 ) + 'ms ' + ( animation.easing || 'linear' ) : 'none';
    
    $letter.css({
     '-webkit-transition' : transition,
     '-moz-transition' : transition,
     '-o-transition' : transition,
     '-ms-transition' : transition,
     'transition' : transition
    })
    .css({
     '-webkit-transform' : transformation,
     '-moz-transform' : transformation,
     '-o-transform' : transformation,
     '-ms-transform' : transformation,
     'transform' : transformation
    });
   
   });
   
  },
  _loadEvents   : function() {
   
   if( this.options.fitText ) {
   
    var _self = this;
    
    $(window).on( 'resize.arctext', function() {
     
     _self._calc();
     
     // apply transformation.
     _self._rotateWord();
     
    });
   
   }
  
  },
  set     : function( opts ) {
   
   if( !opts.radius &&  
    !opts.dir &&
    opts.rotate === 'undefined' ) {
     return false;
   }
   
   this.options.radius = opts.radius || this.options.radius;
   this.options.dir  = opts.dir || this.options.dir;
   
   if( opts.rotate !== undefined ) {
    this.options.rotate = opts.rotate;
   } 
   
   this._calc();
   
   this._rotateWord( opts.animation );
   
  },
  destroy    : function() {
   
   this.options.radius = -1;
   this._rotateWord();
   this.$letters.removeData('x y a center');
   this.$el.removeData('arctext');
   $(window).off('.arctext');
   
  }
 };
 
 var logError    = function( message ) {
  if ( this.console ) {
   console.error( message );
  }
 };
 
 $.fn.arctext   = function( options ) {
 
  if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {
   
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );
   
   this.each(function() {
   
    var instance = $.data( this, 'arctext' );
    
    if ( !instance ) {
     logError( "cannot call methods on arctext prior to initialization; " +
     "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
     return;
    }
    
    if ( !$.isFunction( instance[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {
     logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for arctext instance" );
     return;
    }
    
    instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );
   
   });
  
  } 
  else {
  
   this.each(function() {
   
    var instance = $.data( this, 'arctext' );
    if ( !instance ) {
     $.data( this, 'arctext', new $.Arctext( options, this ) );
    }
   });
  
  }
  
  return this;
  
 };
 
})( jQuery );

/*
 * CircleType 0.36
 * Peter Hrynkow
 * Copyright 2014, Licensed GPL & MIT
 *
*/

$.fn.circleType = function(options) {

    var self = this,
        settings = {
        dir: 1,
        position: 'relative',
    };
    if (typeof($.fn.lettering) !== 'function') {
        console.log('Lettering.js is required');
        return;
    }
    return this.each(function () {
    
        if (options) { 
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }
        var elem = this, 
            delta = (180 / Math.PI),
            fs = parseInt($(elem).css('font-size'), 10),
            ch = parseInt($(elem).css('line-height'), 10) || fs,
            txt = elem.innerHTML.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;'),
            letters, 
            center;

        elem.innerHTML = txt
        $(elem).lettering();

        elem.style.position =  settings.position;

        letters = elem.getElementsByTagName('span');
        center = Math.floor(letters.length / 2)
                
        var layout = function () {
            var tw = 0, 
                i,
                offset = 0,
                minRadius, 
                origin, 
                innerRadius,
                l, style, r, transform;
                                                
            for (i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
                tw += letters[i].offsetWidth;
            }
            minRadius = (tw / Math.PI) / 2 + ch;
            
            if (settings.fluid && !settings.fitText) {
                settings.radius = Math.max(elem.offsetWidth / 2, minRadius);
            }    
            else if (!settings.radius) {
                settings.radius = minRadius;
            }   
            
            if (settings.dir === -1) {
                origin = 'center ' + (-settings.radius + ch) / fs + 'em';
            } else {
                origin = 'center ' + settings.radius / fs + 'em';
            }

            innerRadius = settings.radius - ch;
                
            for (i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
                l = letters[i];
                offset += l.offsetWidth / 2 / innerRadius * delta;
                l.rot = offset;                      
                offset += l.offsetWidth / 2 / innerRadius * delta;
            }   
            for (i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
                l = letters[i]
                style = l.style
                r = (-offset * settings.dir / 2) + l.rot * settings.dir            
                transform = 'rotate(' + r + 'deg)';
                    
                style.position = 'absolute';
                style.left = '50%';
                style.marginLeft = -(l.offsetWidth / 2) / fs + 'em';

                style.webkitTransform = transform;
                style.MozTransform = transform;
                style.OTransform = transform;
                style.msTransform = transform;
                style.transform = transform;

                style.webkitTransformOrigin = origin;
                style.MozTransformOrigin = origin;
                style.OTransformOrigin = origin;
                style.msTransformOrigin = origin;
                style.transformOrigin = origin;
                if(settings.dir === -1) {
                    style.bottom = 0;
                }
            }
            
            if (settings.fitText) {
                if (typeof($.fn.fitText) !== 'function') {
                    console.log('FitText.js is required when using the fitText option');
                } else {
                    $(elem).fitText();
                    $(window).resize(function () {
                        updateHeight();
                    });
                }
            }    
            updateHeight();
            
            if (typeof settings.callback === 'function') {
                // Execute our callback with the element we transformed as `this`
                settings.callback.apply(elem);
            }
        };
        
        var getBounds = function (elem) {
            var docElem = document.documentElement,
                box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
            return {
                top: box.top + window.pageYOffset - docElem.clientTop,
                left: box.left + window.pageXOffset - docElem.clientLeft,
                height: box.height
            };
        };       
        
        var updateHeight = function () {
            var mid = getBounds(letters[center]),
                first = getBounds(letters[0]),
                h;
            if (mid.top < first.top) {
                h = first.top - mid.top + first.height;
            } else {
                h = mid.top - first.top + first.height;
            }
            elem.style.height = h + 'px';  
        }

        if (settings.fluid && !settings.fitText) {
            $(window).resize(function () {
                layout();
            });
        }    

        if (document.readyState !== "complete") {
            elem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            $(window).load(function () {
                elem.style.visibility = 'visible';
                layout();
            });
        } else {
            layout();
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<form id="myform">
    
    <select id="fs"> 
        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
        <option value="Verdana ">Verdana </option>
        <option value="Impact ">Impact </option>
        <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
    </select>
    
    <select id="size">
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="32">32</option>
        <option value="34">34</option>
        <option value="36">36</option>
    </select>
   
   <div id="demo1">Here is some text I would like to see in a different shape.</div>
   
</form>

<br/>


<div id="container" class="changeMe">
Hello World 1234567890<div id="float">
        
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://circletype.labwire.ca/js/circletype.js"></script>
<script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/js/jquery.arctext.js"></script>
```

Comment: "Wiggle" could be done using arctext and putting one piece bending one way  next to another bending the other way.  To do more than that...have you looked into D3 or some of the other more robust graphics libraries?

Comment: No I have not but I will thank-you. For some reason arc text doesn't work I believe I have the script

Comment: You have to make sure to import the libraries in the right order -- basically from top to bottom.  If you're trying to have ArcText operate on a <div> that hasn't yet been created, it won't work.  Try moving it into the "head" section instead.

Comment: what about circle type how can i change the code so i can make more designs not just circle every time i try to make a different design it just turns into a circle

Comment: My guess is your problem is with this code: $("#demo1").click(function(){
    $('.changeMe').circleType("fitText:true", $(this).attr('radius: 180'));
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your problem is with this code:

```
   $("#demo1").click(function(){
        $('.changeMe').circleType("fitText:true", $(this).attr('radius: 180'));
    });
```

You do not have a proper div matching this code.  I'll come back to this in a minute but first you should know that usually one does not go in and edit a library directly.  My suggestion is that you play with your code inside of its own separate `<script>` tags.

So maybe after you finish loading your libraries:

```
<script>
$("#fs").change(function() {
    //alert($(this).val());
    $('.changeMe').css("font-family", $(this).val());
});

$("#size").change(function() {
    $('.changeMe').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});

$("#demo1").click(function(){
    $('.changeMe').circleType("fitText:true", $(this).attr('radius: 180'));
});
</script>
```

Then you just need to modify your HTML so that you have a demo1 div that is *not* a button:

```
<div id="demo1">Here is some text I would like to see in a different shape.</div>
```

This code probably likes to run against regular old HTML text and not a button.

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE:**  I got rid of your redundant libraries and simplified your code.  This example should work when placed between the `<body>` tags in an HTML document.  Click each line to see it in action.  I also moved your stylesheets into the document `<head>` tag where they belong.

```
   <div id="demo1">Here is some text I would like to see in a different shape.</div>
   <div id="demo2">Here is some text I would like to see in a different shape.</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://circletype.labwire.ca/js/circletype.js"></script>
<script src="http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/js/jquery.arctext.js"></script>

<script>
    $("#demo1").click(function(){
        $('#demo1').circleType({radius:384});
    });

    $("#demo2").click(function(){
        $('#demo2').circleType({radius:384, dir:-1});
    });     
</script>
```

Comment: Iit doesn't work look at the code above I modified it still doesn't work

Comment: Arctext is looking like it likes to be installed using Bower.  CircleType looks like you can run it as a jQuery plugin.  Did you install ArcText or did you just mash these two libraries together?  Did you grab the CSS and whatever other files Arctext needs to run?

Comment: No I just mashed the together. I'll get the CSS and all the other stuff for arc text